# Datetime strptime in Python pandas : what's wrong?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, strptime

```
import datetime as datetime
datetime.strptime('2013-01-01 09:10:12', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

produces

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 import datetime as datetime
>   ----> 2 datetime.strptime('2013-01-01 09:10:12', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>         3 z = minidf['Dates']
>         4 z
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'

my goal is to convert a pandas dataframe column whose format is still a data object

```
import datetime as datetime
#datetime.strptime('2013-01-01 09:10:12', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
z = minidf['Dates']

0     2015-05-13 23:53:00
1     2015-05-13 23:53:00
2     2015-05-13 23:33:00
3     2015-05-13 23:30:00
4     2015-05-13 23:30:00
5     2015-05-13 23:30:00
6     2015-05-13 23:30:00
7     2015-05-13 23:30:00
8     2015-05-13 23:00:00
9     2015-05-13 23:00:00
10    2015-05-13 22:58:00
Name: Dates, dtype: object
```

the bonus question is, i got this column using `pd.read_csv` function from a larger file with more columns. Is it possible to pass parameters such that `pd.read_csv` directly converts this to `dtype: datetime64[ns]` format

Comment: use `datetime.datetime.strptime('2013-01-01 09:10:12', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` to refer the `datetime` class within the `datetime` module

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you can use for converting [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
print pd.to_datetime('2013-01-01 09:10:12', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
2013-01-01 09:10:12

print pd.to_datetime('2013-01-01 09:10:12')
2013-01-01 09:10:12
```

If you need convert in function [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), add parameter `parse_dates`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename',  parse_dates=['Dates'])
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""Dates
2015-05-13 23:53:00
2015-05-13 23:53:00
2015-05-13 23:33:00
2015-05-13 23:30:00
2015-05-13 23:30:00
2015-05-13 23:30:00
2015-05-13 23:30:00
2015-05-13 23:30:00
2015-05-13 23:00:00
2015-05-13 23:00:00
2015-05-13 22:58:00
"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp),  parse_dates=['Dates'])
print df
                 Dates
0  2015-05-13 23:53:00
1  2015-05-13 23:53:00
2  2015-05-13 23:33:00
3  2015-05-13 23:30:00
4  2015-05-13 23:30:00
5  2015-05-13 23:30:00
6  2015-05-13 23:30:00
7  2015-05-13 23:30:00
8  2015-05-13 23:00:00
9  2015-05-13 23:00:00
10 2015-05-13 22:58:00

print df.dtypes
Dates    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Another solution with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
print pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])
```

Sample:

```
print df
                  Dates
0   2015-05-13 23:53:00
1   2015-05-13 23:53:00
2   2015-05-13 23:33:00
3   2015-05-13 23:30:00
4   2015-05-13 23:30:00
5   2015-05-13 23:30:00
6   2015-05-13 23:30:00
7   2015-05-13 23:30:00
8   2015-05-13 23:00:00
9   2015-05-13 23:00:00
10  2015-05-13 22:58:00

print df.dtypes
Dates    object

df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])
print df
                 Dates
0  2015-05-13 23:53:00
1  2015-05-13 23:53:00
2  2015-05-13 23:33:00
3  2015-05-13 23:30:00
4  2015-05-13 23:30:00
5  2015-05-13 23:30:00
6  2015-05-13 23:30:00
7  2015-05-13 23:30:00
8  2015-05-13 23:00:00
9  2015-05-13 23:00:00
10 2015-05-13 22:58:00

print df.dtypes
Dates    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 7):

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'

[`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) is not available on `datetime` but on `datetime.datetime`

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('2013-01-01 09:10:12', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 9, 10, 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

importing only the module

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2013-01-01 09:10:12', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 9, 10, 12)
```

importing the class from the module into current context:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('2013-01-01 09:10:12', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 9, 10, 12)
>>>
```